# Trying to override a class function but it doesnt and uses the default function it inherits from

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to create custom move functions for my enemies but when I try to override the move function so it uses the new custom move function it doesnt and instead uses the original move function that the class inherits from.

so First I define it. (Note I cut a lot of unnecessary code that should make it easier to read)

```
Monster = {}

function Monster:new()
    local obj = {
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
    }
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    self.__index = self
    return obj
end
```

The move function

```
function Monster:move(values)
   x,y = values.x , values.y
   print(x,y)
end
```

new class based on monster.

```
Zigzag_monster = Monster:new()
```

Note: there is arguments here I simplified it

```
function Zigzag_monster:new()
  local zigzag = Monster:new()
  zigzag.amplitude = 5

  setmetatable(zigzag, self)
    self.__index = self
  return zigzag
end


function Zigzag_monster:move(values)
      x,y = values.x * 2, values.y * 2
end


default_monster = Monster:new("default",Speed_Image,20,5,150,20)
Zigzag = Zigzag_monster:new("Zigzag",Zigzag_Image,50,25,100,30)
```

in another script I call these global variables like so Default_monster:Move(values) and they both should produce different values but Zigzag produces the same values as Defualt, can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

I will include the full code just in case there is actually a difference.

```
local Default_Image = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/Enemies/monster.png")
local Speed_Image = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/Enemies/monster_speed.png")
local Zigzag_Image = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/Enemies/Zigzag.png")

Monster = {}

function Monster:new(name, sprite,health,damage,speed,xp_yield)
    local obj = {
        name = name,
        sprite = sprite,
        health = health,
        damage = damage,
        speed = speed,
        xp_yield = xp_yield,
        -- argumentless
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        timer = 1.0,
        max_timer = 1.0,
        decay_timer = 0
    }
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    self.__index = self
    return obj
end

function Monster:spawn(position)
    local new_monster = Monster:new(self.name,self.sprite,self.health,self.damage,self.speed,self.xp_yield)

    new_monster.x, new_monster.y = position.x, position.y

    return new_monster
end

function Monster:move(target,dt)
    local dx = target.x - self.x
    local dy = target.y - self.y
    local distance = math.sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
    if distance > 0 then
      self.x = self.x + self.speed * dt * dx / distance
      self.y = self.y + self.speed * dt * dy / distance
    end
end

function Monster:attack(target)
    target.health = target.health - self.damage
end

-- Define subclass
Zigzag_monster = Monster:new()

function Zigzag_monster:new(name, sprite,health,damage,speed,xp_yield)
  local zigzag = Monster:new(name, sprite,health,damage,speed,xp_yield)
  zigzag.direction = 0
  zigzag.zigzag = false
  zigzag.amplitude = 3
  zigzag.frequency = 5

  setmetatable(zigzag, self)
    self.__index = self
  return zigzag
end

function Zigzag_monster:move(target, dt)
    local playerX, playerY = target.x, target.y
  
    -- Determine enemy direction based on player position
    self.direction = math.atan2(playerY - self.y, playerX - self.x)
    
    -- Move enemy towards player
    local speed = 100 -- adjust as needed
    self.x = self.x + speed * math.cos(self.direction) * dt
    self.y = self.y + speed * math.sin(self.direction) * dt
    
    -- Calculate zigzag movement
    local offset = self.amplitude * math.sin(self.frequency * love.timer.getTime())
    
    -- Apply zigzag offset to enemy position
    if self.zigzag then
      self.x = self.x + offset * math.cos(self.direction + math.pi/2)
      self.y = self.y + offset * math.sin(self.direction + math.pi/2)
    else
      self.x = self.x - offset * math.cos(self.direction + math.pi/2)
      self.y = self.y - offset * math.sin(self.direction + math.pi/2)
    end
    
    -- Reverse zigzag direction at edges of screen
    if self.x < 0 or self.x > love.graphics.getWidth() or self.y < 0 or self.y > love.graphics.getHeight() then
      self.zigzag = not self.zigzag
    end
end

local monster_data = {
    default_monster = {
    name = "Defualt",
    sprite = Default_Image,
    health = 10,
    damage = 10,
    speed = 50,
    xp_yield = 10
    },

    speed_monster = {
    name = "Speed",
    sprite = Speed_Image,
    health = 20,
    damage = 5,
    speed = 150,
    xp_yield = 20
    },

    zigzag_monster = {
    name = "Zigzag",
    sprite = Speed_Image,
    health = 50,
    damage = 25,
    speed = 100,
    xp_yield = 30
    }
}

Default_monster = Monster:new("defualt",Default_Image,10,10,50,10)
Speed_monster = Monster:new("Speed",Speed_Image,20,5,150,20)
Zigzag = Zigzag_monster:new("Zigzag",Zigzag_Image,50,25,100,30)
```

Comment: Why are you writing to global variables `x, y` rather than "instance" fields `self.x`, `self.y`?

Comment: If you are talking about the top code those aren't proper code it was simply an example, if you look at the bottom that's how my code actually is but I simplified it in the top for you to read easier.

Comment: `in another script I call these global variables like so Default_monster:Move(values) and they both should produce different values but Zigzag produces the same values as Defualt` - show your another script

Comment: `function Move_monsters(dt)
  for _, monster in ipairs(monsters) do
    monster:move(player,dt)
  end
end` I loop through a table that contains all the monsters and I simply call the monster:move() function I simply add new monsters to the table. `function spawnMonster()
  local position = Spawn_location(player,{width = sizes,height = sizes},monsters)
  local randomNumber = love.math.random(1, 100)
  local monster = nil
  if randomNumber <= 20 then
    monster = Speed_monster:spawn(position)
  else
    monster = Zigzag:spawn(position)
  end
  table.insert(monsters, monster)
end`

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a few hours of banging my head I figured it out, It was the way I was instancing my monsters, I have to figure out a different way of instancing but simply this code.

```
function Monster:Spawn(position)
  local new_monster = Monster:new(self.name ,self.sprite, self.health, self.damage, self.speed, self.xp_yield)
  new_monster.x, new_monster.y = position.x,position.y

  return new_monster
end
```

would create a new instance but only with the original Monster Class so when I call say Zigzag_monster:move it is using the monster class and not the new zigzag class.

Comment: I just looked at my original post and I noticed I didnt even include this bit of code, very bad but I did include the full script at the bottom.